# Paginating data by last active when rows constantly change

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm looking for pagination approaches to be used on data that is constantly changing (around 1 - 3 updates per minute).

I have a conversation list with the following structure

```
conversation : id, user_id, last_message, last_active
```

The most active conversations change 1 to 3 times per minute and so the `last_active` column is updated whenever a change is registered. A user can have 100+ conversations.

The problem I have is paginating the data when the `last_active` value is changing.

If the data is static, you can simply do the pagination with a 'ORDER BY DESC last_active LIMIT n, 15' query on MySQL. But because last_active is constantly changing, the ordering of items can change and so just never show up on the list (or show up multiple times).

For example, if the limit was 3 per page and my data looked like this :

```
{id : 1, last_active : 10:14:41} 
{id : 2, last_active : 10:14:31}
{id : 3, last_active : 10:13:55}
[Page - 1]

{id : 4, last_active : 10:13:30}
{id : 5, last_active : 10:12:06}
{id : 6, last_active : 10:11:10}
[Page - 2]

{id : 7, last_active : 10:10:20}
{id : 8, last_active : 10:10:06}
{id : 9, last_active : 10:09:22}
[Page - 3]
```

Now, when the user is on the second page, if an update is carried out to `id = 7`, it is pushed to the top of the query by the `ORDER BY` clause, and it never shows up on page 3.

What's the best way to organize this so that I can paginate this data without losing rows or duplicating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of approaches. The issue is that you need to define what the user expectations are:

1) I want my data to always be current. In which case I would expect and understand that page 2 is current and that my previously seen page 1 may have changed. I would be ok with that if I wanted my data to truly be current.

2) I don't care that much about up to the second results and I might be thrown off if for example #7 never shows because it switched pages at some point. In this case I would want to show the results for page 2 that were valid as of the time I made my initial page 1 request. This would involve caching or adding some other field. This could be inconvenient except for the probability that if a user is more interested in convenience/clarity rather than exact database data then I doubt they are going to go page by page all the way to say, 20, in order to find an item which means you only need to cache the first few pages of items on your initial fetch.

Then adjust your code to fetch from these cached results if 1) the pagination is 2-5 and 2) the time of the cache is not too old (say 10 min - we don't want someone to click on page 2 if page 1 has been sitting there for an hour over lunch break).

I would think most end users would fall in the #2 category. If they did not then they are probably techie enough to not be confused and you can also add a note.